# Revert a document revision

Tags: google-docs-api

In revisions document list api, is possible revert a document revision?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download any revisions as described in the docs:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#downloading_individual_revisions

Comment: Ok thanks but I want to change the current revision without having to download the document. In Google Docs front when I see the revisions I can revert a revision. This functionality is that I need know if is possible with api.

Comment: You can publish a doc at a specific revision (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#publishing_documents_by_publishing_a_single_revision) but there's no way to restore a revision using the API.